# $f\in (W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega))\setminus C(\bar{\Omega})$, $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ imply $f\in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Q1:
Let $p\geq 1$, and let $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega)$. Assume also
$f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Is it true that
$f\in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$ even if $f\notin C(\bar{\Omega})$ ?

Thanks

Comment: You currently have two opposite answers to this question, [@Nate](https://mathoverflow.net/a/290638)'s saying 'yes' and [yours](https://mathoverflow.net/a/290674) saying 'no'.  Do you disagree with Nate's answer?  Or is it just that you are taking the question to mean "*must* $f$ lie in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$" and Nate is taking it to mean "*can* $f$ lie in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$"?  (You have used 'is' instead of 'must' or 'can', which, I think, is ambiguous.)

Comment: I guess the problem is that the title and the text have different interpretations.

Comment: The question is really what do you mean by $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$? Do you mean the trace of $f$ is zero? If so, then $f\in W^{1,p}_0$ (provided boundary is Lipschitz)? If not, then you should clarify what $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ means.

Comment: @LSpice. I rephrased the question. It was a bit confusing. It turns out to be very simple. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jeff. Sorry the for the earlier confusing version of the question. Now you see I meant $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ in the pointwise sense, e.g. $f=0$ on $\Omega^{c}$. You  said (provided the boundary is Lipschitz). But this is necessary for the $L^{p}$ boundedness of the trace. I believe it is not required to define the trace. Example: $f\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$ then $f\in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$ no matter how rough the boundary is.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Let $\Omega$ be a domain. (no smoothness conditions on $\Omega$). The trace of a function $f\in C(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty} (\Omega) $ exists in the pointwise sense.

Comment: @Medo: Let $\Omega=(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^1$.  Let $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ which is in $C(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$.  How will you define its trace at $x=0 \in \partial \Omega$?

Comment: Yes, but the equivalence between zero trace and $W^{1,p}_0$ requires Lipschitz boundary.

Comment: The trace is not defined for arbitrary domains; you need some boundary regularity. Consider the punctured plane $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$. Then the trace of a function is pointwise evaluation at $x=0$, which is not well-defined unless $p>n$. The unboundedness of $\Omega$ is not essential in the example.

Comment: @Jeff. I do not understand why would we want to know the trace at a puncture point. When I said the trace of a function $f\in C(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, the assumption that $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ should be understood, since we are talking about traces.

Comment: @Jeff. Could you give an example for the necessity of the boundary being Lipschitz for the mere existence of a trace of a $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ function on $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: @Nate. However $\sin(1/x)∉W^{1,p}((0,1))$ for any $ p≥1$. Or is that your point ?

Comment: @Medo The punctured point is part of the boundary...

Comment: @Medo Take $\Omega = B^0(0,1)\setminus \{x_1=0\}$ and set $f=1$ when $x_1>0$ and $f=-1$ when $x_1<0$. What is the trace of $f$ on the portion of $\partial \Omega$ where $x_1=0$? You can construct similar examples on connected domains.

Comment: @NateEldredge gave a good answer to the only sensible (and non-trivial) interpretation of this question.

Comment: @Jeff. Once again, this $f$ is not a $W^{1,p}$ function on the given $\Omega$. Would you like to show/refer to an example that shows there is a minimal smoothness requirement on the boundary necessary for the existence (not $L^{p}$ boundedness) of the trace of a Sobolev function?

Comment: Yes it is $W^{1,p}$. Its weak derivative is identically zero in $\Omega$. Note in the definition of weak derivative you test with functions $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$; in particular, $\phi$ vanishes in a neighborhood of the set where $\{x_1=0\}$.

Comment: I shouldn't even say "weak" derivative; in this case $f \in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ (in the sense in Evans book, which means $f$ and all its derivatives are uniformly continuous on $\Omega$).

Comment: @Jeff. Okay. You are right it. It is a $W^{1,p}$ function on that $\Omega$. Now update $\Omega$ to be only one of the two halves, say the half with $x_{1}>0$. This is a domain that is not Lipschitz right? Why does not it have trace $=1$ on $x_{1}=0$ ?

Comment: Either half has a Lipschitz boundary and the trace is well-defined for either half considered separately. But $\Omega$ as a whole does not have a Lipschtiz boundary. (Take $x\in \partial \Omega$ with $x_1=0$. For $\partial \Omega$ to be Lipschitz, there must exist $r>0$ such that $\Omega \cap B(x,r) = \{x \, : \, \gamma(x) > 0\}$ for a Lipschitz function $\gamma$, which is clearly not true).

Comment: @Jeff. Thanks a lot. I did learn a lot from your comments. One last concern though. How modify $\Omega$ (the unit ball minus $\{x_{1}=0\}$) to be connected, but still have $f=sgn(x_{1})$, $x\in \Omega$,  a $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ function without a trace, somewhere on the boundary) because the boundary is not Lipschitz? Thanks again for your patience

Comment: Union $\Omega$ with a small ball $B^0(0,\epsilon)$ to make it connected, and multiply $f$ by a smooth bump function $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfying $\phi=0$ in $B(0,2\epsilon)$ and $\phi=1$ for $|x|>3\epsilon$. The new function will agree with $\text{sgn}(x_1)$ for $|x|>3\epsilon$.

Comment: @Jeff. So, we still do not have an example where $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega_{i})$, $i=1,2$, $\Omega_{1}$ is a domain not Lipschitz and $f$ does not have trace on $\partial \Omega_{1}$, while $\Omega_{2}$ is a Lipschitz domain and $f$ does have trace on $\Omega_{2}$. This will show that Lipschitz condition on the boundary is necessary for a $W^{1,p}$ function to have trace. Notice that the domain in your previous examples are Lipschitz. Thanks

Comment: The previous domains are not Lipschitz. You need to review the definition of a Lipschitz domain.

Comment: @Jeff. I am confused. On Jan 16 at 22:40, you commented "Either half has a Lipschitz boundary and the trace is well-defined for either half considered separately". Did you mean to say neither "Neither half has a Lipschitz boundary" ?

Comment: No, what I said is correct. The whole domain is made up of two connected components, each of which has a Lipschitz boundary, but the union does *not* have a Lipschitz boundary. To have a Lipschitz boundary, you need to be able to touch the boundary with a cone from the exterior, which is impossible along a slit.

Comment: @Jeff. Okay. Let us now connect the two half balls by the small ball $B(0; \epsilon )$ as you suggested. Will  $x\mapsto sing (x_{1})$ still be  a $W^{1,p}$ function on the connected domain ?

Comment: I already explained this to you; no, but you can modify it with a bump function so it is $W^{1,p}$ and equal to $\text{sign}(x_1)$ away from $B(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74341/discussion-between-jeff-and-medo).

Answer (score 2):

(The question got modified and this may not answer it anymore.)

It is possible to have a function $f$ which is $C^\infty$ and bounded on $\Omega$ and is in $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, yet does not have any continuous extension to $\overline{\Omega}$; in particular, setting $f = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ does not result in a continuous function.

Let $\Omega$ be some domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \ge 2$, and let $\varphi$ be some smooth bump function supported inside the unit ball and with  $\varphi(0) = 1$.  Let $\varphi_\epsilon(x) = \varphi(x/\epsilon)$.  With a change of variables, you can compute that $\|\varphi_\epsilon\|_{W^{1,p}} \approx \epsilon^{d-1}$.

Now choose a sequence of disjoint open balls $B_n$ inside $\Omega$ of radius $r_n$, where $\sum r_n < \infty$, whose centers $x_n$ converge to some $x \in \partial \Omega$.  Let $g_n(x) = \varphi_{r_n}(x-x_n)$, which is compactly supported inside $B_n$ and has $g_n(x_n)=1$.  Then the sum $f = \sum_n g_n$ converges in $W^{1,1}_0(\Omega)$, but $f$ is greater than $1/2$ everywhere on some neighborhood of $\{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$, so $f$ cannot be continuous up to the boundary, even after modification on a null set.  Moreover, $f$ is continuous (even $C^\infty$) inside $\Omega$, since the sum is locally finite inside $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate. I am a little confused though. You are saying $f \in W^{1,1}_{0}(\Omega)$ yet there can be a subset of the boundary with positive Lebesgue surface measure on which $f\neq 0$. Does not the latter exclude $f$ from $W^{1,1}_{0}(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: @Medo: No, that's not true.  $f$ is zero everywhere on the boundary.  Note that every $g_n$ is compactly supported inside $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks a gain. What do you mean by "so f does not vanish continuously at the boundary"  ?

Comment: @Medo: Poor phrasing.  I meant that although $f$ does vanish on the boundary, it cannot be continuous up to the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No.

There can be  $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$
such that  $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ but  $f\notin W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$.

If $f\notin C({\bar{\Omega}})$, then its trace on $\partial \Omega$ can be different from zero, and in that case  $f\notin W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$.

Example: simply the characteristic function $\chi_{\Omega}$

The trace of a function $f \in C(\Omega)$ at $x\in \partial \Omega$ is the limit 
of $f$ when we move from the interior of $\Omega$ toward $x$.
If $f\in C(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ then its trace exists. If $f\in C({\bar{\Omega}})$
then the trace (the limit) at any $x\in\partial \Omega$ coincides with $f(x)$.
So, assuming $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and continuity on $\Omega$ are not enough.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this answer (and question). Functions in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ are equivalence classes of functions defined on the open set $\Omega$. Aside from the fact that $\partial \Omega$ has measure zero, the values of $f$ on $\partial \Omega$ are not even part of the definition of a Sobolev space function. There is no sensible way to say that the characteristic function of $\Omega$ as an element of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is zero on the boundary. This is why the notion of trace was invented (and trace is not exactly the limit of $f$ as you move to the boundary; it is a bit more subtle).

Comment: Also, a function in $C(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ need not have a trace; just consider $\sin(1/x)$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$.